# Drag and Drop to swap input fields

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm currently trying to rewrite a desktop app to something that can be run in a browser. I have (more or less) the idea how to rewrite most of the features, but there's one in particular that I'm not sure how to tackle.

So the app does have text fields (hundreds of them). You can click any of them and type some data. It's all fine till now, but next thing is, you can drag and drop to swap them (or content of them) with each other.

[image]

On desktop drag and drop is done with right mouse button, but I'm not sure if that's feasible for web. I was also looking up some drag and drop libraries, but they all seems to handle more "static" elements like divs, images, etc, but never input fields (maybe because they're stealing click events?).

Does anyone in here have a clever idea how to achieve something like this? Maybe someone else have done something similar or maybe it would be easier to do if XYZ? Ideally in React (because that's what I'm using for rest of the app), but if it's work in any other way maybe I'll be able to adopt it.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I use https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd 
The main idea is using `Draggable` and `Droppable` components. Also, it's possible to handle both clicks and drag events. But it's complex a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This lib seems nice but it looks like it's more for moving list elements from one to another instead of swapping them. Would that be possible with custom handlers?